# Curl + Read web content with absolute url of the css and javascript resources

Tags: php, curl

I'm reading a external website using PHP CURL which has got css and javascript calls as below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/scripts.js'></script>
```

If the website is http://mywebsite.com, I need to get the content as below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mywebsite.com/styles.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mywebsite.com/js/scripts.js'></script>
```

Is there any option to do so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regular expression

If your results from curl_exec is saved as $result:

```
if (!preg_match('/src="https?:\/\/"/', $result)) {
    $result = preg_replace('/src="(http:\/\/([^\/]+)\/)?([^"]+)"/', "src=\"http://mywebsite.com/\\3\"", $result);
}
if (!preg_match('/href="https?:\/\/"/', $result)) {
    $result = preg_replace('/href="(http:\/\/([^\/]+)\/)?([^"]+)"/', "href=\"http://mywebsite.com/\\3\"", $result);
}
```